# Como salvar um input em um arquivo txt

Tags: python, python-3.x

Como eu posso salvar um input de um usuário que é registrado no meu programa de forma que mesmo depois dele fechar o programa e abri-lo novamente seja possível imprimir apenas o input desse usuário? É possível fazer isso usando um arquivo .txt?

Comment: O que seria "usuário" nesse contexto? O usuário do próprio sistema operacional executando o seu programa ou uma pessoa qualquer? Se for a segunda opção, como irá identificar um usuário?

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a que melhor por causa disto. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/101).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim é possível. Você pode primeiro verificar se o arquivo.txt existe e se ele possui algum conteúdo. Para verificar se ele existe basta utilizar a função `os.path.exists(path)`.

Depois de entrar no bloco `if` o programa recebe o input do usuário e escreve esse input no arquivo.txt. Caso não entre no `if` porque o arquivo existe e possui um conteúdo, o programa imprimirá o que o usuário digitou na última vez. Exemplo:

```
import os

fn = 'arquivo.txt'

if os.path.exists(fn):
    with open(fn) as file:
        text = file.read()
else:
    text = None

if not text:
    with open(fn,'w') as file:
        text = input("Digite alguma coisa: ")
        file.write(text)
else:
    print("Você já tinha digitado:",text)
```